# Coverter Html para texto

Tags: angular, ckeditor

Estou em um projeto para criação de um site com angular, o site deve ter um editor de texto integrado, estou pensando em usar o nd2-ckeditor (aceito sugestões) , a questão é que o editor me retorna um texto com as tags html, isso não é um problema se tenho apenas que mostrar o texto na tela, mas quero saber se tem como "converter" esse texto html para um texto sem as tags.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode retirar as tags do html do documento CKEditor desta forma:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt )
  {
    var editor = evt.editor;

   editor.on('change', function (e) { 
   var text =  editor.editable().getText();
   console.log(text);
    });
 });
```

Exemplo:
https://codepen.io/edsonperotoni/pen/ZEEooxW

Referência:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140043/how-to-strip-html-tags-with-jquery
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895795/getting-non-html-text-from-ckeditor